# React Redux mapStateToProps is re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, rerender

I'm having an issue where my component is being re-render and it shouldn't (I'm always sending the same set of data). Later I found out that if my **mapStateToProps** looks like this:

```
function mapStateToProps({reducerContent},ownProps) {
    return {
        ...reducerContent
    }
}
```

it won't re-render (if I send the same set of data) but this form of **mapStateToProps** will re-render my component:

```
function mapStateToProps({reducerContent},ownProps) {
    return {
        data: {
            ...reducerContent
        }
    }
}
```

Down below you can find my reducer and component.
reducer: (action.data is shallow object):

```
const reducerContent = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch ( action.type ){
        case types.GET_CONTENT:
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.data
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Component (will be further developed):

```
import React, {Component}   from 'react';
import {connect}            from 'react-redux';

class Content extends Component {
    render() {
        return {this.props.content}
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({reducerContent},ownProps) {
    return {
        ...reducerContent
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,null)(Content)
```

Comment: it will re-render because you are defining a new prop `data` with your values

Comment: Ok, but it shouldn't re-render after this prop had been added (on lets say first request) and no changes in reducer data has been made, or?

Comment: Your two different `mapStateToProps` aren't equivalent.

Comment: componentShouldUpdate will allow you to make a rule whereby you can define a better equality check on `data`.  Otherwise, you are creating a new object and only references are compared.

Comment: @Colin yes, they are (checked in console and tried to return static data).

Comment: @DavinTryon shouldComponentUpdate will be deprecated but fair point.

Comment: @mihajloWR No, they're not. Also, the docs don't say `shouldComponentUpdate` will be deprecated.

Comment: @Colin sorry, read the wrong lifecycle.

    const reducerContent = (state = {}, action) => {
        switch ( action.type ){
            case types.GET_CONTENT:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    title: 'title',
                    description: 'description',
                    body: 'body'
                };

            default:
                return state;
        }
    };

How is this not returning the same data every time?

Answer (score 1):

`connect` is implement as a `PureComponent` i.e. it does a shallow comparison of the values being supplied from `mapStateToProps` and decides whether to re-render or not.

Now when you supply data like

```
{
    data: {
        ...reducerContent
    }
}
```

The shallow comparison fails, since you cloned reducerContainer and hence `nextProps.data` isn't equal to `this.props.data`. In order to avoid such situations, you generally go for [**`memoization`**](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-memoize-in-javascript-51d07d19430e). For this you can either make use of [**`reselect`**](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) or implement a memoized function yourself

with select your mapStateToProps would look like

```
const getReducedDataSelector = createSelector(
   state => state.reducerContent,
   (reducedContent) => ({...reducedContent})
);
function mapStateToProps(state,ownProps) {
    return {
        data: getReducedDataSelector(state, ownProps);
    }
}
```

In the above case `getReducedDataSelector` can be implement using a custom memoization method as well